# status of scanf("%d", &num) is 0 or 1

Tags: c

I am following the instruction of C Primer Plus and composed the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int num;
    int x = scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

When run it :

```
$ ./a.out
t
0
$ ./a.out
2
1
```

How could scanf detect a value of "0" or "1"?

Comment: Perhaps [a good `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) help?

Comment: What did you think the return value would be?

Comment: The return value from `scanf()` is the number of assignments (or EOF in case of premature error). In your case, with the "t" input, `scanf()` reports `0` assignments, with the "2" input it reports `1` assignment.

Comment: `printf("%d", x);` -> `printf("%d", num);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` is defined such that

> On success, the function returns the number of items successfully read. This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens. In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

```
NAME
           scanf,  fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf 

       ...

RETURN VALUE
       These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
       and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
       event of an early matching failure.

       The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
       the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
       also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
       for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
       error.
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't detect that value, it returns it. It reads an integer and puts it inside `num`. The return value of `scanf` is not the value it reads from user input but number of values read, which in your case can be a maximum of 1.